# Run a function a certain number times in haskell

Tags: haskell

Imagin we are given many positions for example a, b, c, d, e ... and goForward function to go to the next place.
We always start from a and we are supposed to write a function called goTo which takes a number and runs the goForward function on that number times so that we can get the target position.

Example:
given a, b, c, d, e ...

If we run goTo 0, this should return a.
If we run goTo 3, this should return d.

Comment: StackOverflow is *not* a homework service. Make a fair attempt and come back
with *specific* questions about that attempt. See the
[*open letter to students with homework problems*](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems).

Comment: These examples can be just background information. My main point is, since haskell doesn't have while loop and for loop, how can we run a function a certain number of times? Thanks.

Comment: the "workhorse" of Haskell is *recursion*. You can define a simple function `f :: a -> a`, and then make a function `repeatF :: (a -> a) -> Int -> a -> a` that will repeat `f` a given number of times through recursion.

Comment: What are the positions? Alphabet chars? Any objects on a list? Some generable enumerator?

Comment: How recursion can replace loops, as in computing the maximum value of a numeric list: [LYAH-Recursion](http://learnyouahaskell.com/recursion#hello-recursion)

Comment: If you have a list and just want the nth element, you might want to use `!!`.

Answer (score 0):

[Iterate](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:iterate) from the prelude. And from the documentation at that link:

```
>>> take 10 $ iterate (+3) 42
[42,45,48,51,54,57,60,63...
```